# A good guide book or API doc for iTextSharp?

Tags: itext

Can anyone suggest me a a nice book or API document for iTextSharp , I have been struggling while understanding the lib and have resorted to a hit and try methodology which is extremely irritating and time consuming.

Comment: This is the best API guide I can find: https://afterlogic.com/mailbee-net/docs-itextsharp/html/72996b63-c77f-08f8-7de9-c32122d8b8df.htm

Comment: Yeah, that link was good -- a little bit prettier one  back..   https://afterlogic.com/mailbee-net/docs-itextsharp/

Comment: @SilentSojourner Thank you so much, exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @bobwki Not sure about that site - I'm struggling to find information on a very basic thing, namely units of measurement.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Have a look at the series of articles about iTextSharp http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/80/Create-PDFs-in-ASP.NET-getting-started-with-iTextSharp

Comment: I found the documentation from iText5 to be helpful. Even if it isn't the same version it does provide some very helpful examples.
https://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/itext5-building-blocks

Comment: @bluedot it gives me access denied. Any suggestions ?

Comment: @evry1falls, seems iText5 is end of life and has been replaced by iText7.
There is still some accessible documentation at https://kb.itextpdf.com/home/it5kb/examples and https://itextpdf.com/en/resources/api-documentation/itext-5-java

Comment: @bluedot I don't think my task that requires iText5 would extend beyond the iText5 life. Thank you though.