# Making PDF file from C# application

Tags: c#, pdf

How do I make a PDF with C# application?

I would like to make an application which creates a PDF document, but it could be Excel too.

I wish to make a file which contains tables and header.

Comment: Just search some solutions and try out something that suits you. Most probably you have to use thirdParty software

Comment: You could also check out [GemBox.Spreadsheet](https://www.gemboxsoftware.com/spreadsheet), you can create both Excel and PDF files with it so no need for multiple libraries.

Comment: If you need to create or edit both pdf and excel files, I suggest you check Spire.Office, it also has a free version named Free Spire.Office: https://www.nuget.org/packages/FreeSpire.Office/

Answer (score 0):

You could use [ITextSharp](https://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/) to create your PDF file.
And [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151005/create-excel-xls-and-xlsx-file-from-c-sharp) to help you with Excel.

Comment: I saw solution with ITextSharp, but can I design that document?

Comment: Yes. I have already used this library to create and edit a pdf file.

Comment: Look at this tutorial(https://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/80/create-pdfs-in-asp-net-getting-started-with-itextsharp) I got from this post[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9229548/a-good-guide-book-or-api-doc-for-itextsharp] on SO

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [PDFFlow](https://go.pdfflow.io/Making_PDF_library) library for generation of PDF in C#. It has features that you need: tables, multi-page spread tables, repeating areas  (headers, footers, left, right), table repeating headers... and even more unique features (like automatic page creation, multi-level list, word-like tabulation, barcodes/QR codes, etc...) and easy fluent syntax:

```
var DocumentBuilder.New() 
    .AddSection() 
        .AddParagraph("Hello World!").SetFontColor(Color.Red) 
    .ToSection() 
    .AddImageToSection("Smile.png") 
        .AddTable() 
            .AddColumnToTable("Column1").AddColumnToTable("Column2") 
            .AddRow().AddCellToRow("Row1, Cell1").AddCell("Row1, Cell 2") 
        .ToTable() 
            .AddRow().AddCellToRow("Row2, Cell1").AddCell("Row2, Cell 2") 
.ToDocument() 
    .Build("Result.pdf");
```

This is first pages of my business document with multi-page spread table and repeating headers, which I created using this library:
[image]

There are examples with source code and explanation, I found them very useful: [examples](https://go.pdfflow.io/Making_PDF_examples).

Hope, this will help.